# Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi ssh failed

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core

I am attempting to install and use the [Ubuntu Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3) distro on a Raspberry Pi 3 for the first time.

My SD card is formatted in MS_DOS FAT and the the [ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/edge/current/ubuntu-core-16-armhf+raspi3.img.xz) is flashed onto the card.

I have gone through the process of attaching my Pi to a monitor and keyboard and supplying my Ubuntu One email address.
At the end of the process, the monitor supplies ssh details for connecting to the Pi.

I have also generated an **id_rsa.pub** key and supplied it to my Ubuntu One ssh keys area.

With all that done, when I try to ssh into the Pi, I get one of 2 messages.

The first message I got was:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:QrfHNJLLJ4wjeQAPoVK+W0lhI7pfww3liCVI3/IoJCk.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/userx/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/userx/.ssh/known_hosts:29
ECDSA host key for 192.168.0.14 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

After a while, it didn't report the above message but instead requested a password - which by definition Ubuntu Core is not supposed to utilise.

I need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete known Hosts under ~/.ssh/known_hosts then try to reconnect. You should upload the public keys before you start Ubuntu Core configuration.

Comment: The key I'm uploading is the contents of id_rsa.pub. However there is a known_hosts file which contains multiple keys from other ssh connections. Do I need to generate my Ubuntu One key in known_hosts and not id_rsa.pub ???

Comment: Have you tried to use "ssh-keygen -R" command?

Comment: Yes indeed! ssh-keygen -R 192.168.0.14

Comment: The only thing I did differently in my initial attempts was setting the ssh-key after I configured the Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in this message you have saved this host in your know_hosts file. So now, you should remove it:

```
ssh-keygen -R IP_of_your_RPI
```

and after that try to ssh to your RPI.
But please remember, that you cann't have possibility to ssh to them on root account. It depends on ssh daemon configuration: "PermitRootLogin" option in /etc/sshd_config file.

Comment: I have tried you solution before posting and again after reading your post. When I execute the ssh again, I'm asked to confirm I want to continue connecting and I of course respond 'yes'. However, I'm then asked for a password. I don't have one and from what I've read there shouldn't be a password request

Comment: Which username are you using to SSH in? It should be the developer name you chose when creating your Ubuntu One account.

Comment: The username on the personal details page