# Ubuntu Core SSH Raspberry Pi failed is it the hostname?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi 3 to run Ubuntu core.  I have been attempting to setup my SSH cert to work through my Ubuntu One account and have repeatedly failed.

I've been reviewing this question [Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi ssh failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014853/ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi-ssh-failed).

I have created my ssh cert using this command in the terminal of my Ubuntu machine (14.04).

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

I'm leaving the file name the same as `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` with no passwords.

I've already removed the known_hosts file from earlier attempts (each time I re-try I remove it).

When I open up the `id_rsa.pub` file to copy past the contents into UbuntuOne I see a `user@hostname` combination at the end of the string.  Is that supposed to be there?  This value seems to be appended automatically.  Should I remove it?

Comment: The `user@hostname` bit at the end is just the default value for the _Comment_ section. It can be any text really, an doesn't affect usage of the key.

Comment: Thanks..  I have tried it without the 'user@hostname' and UbuntuOne would not take the cert.  The ssh (coming from my terminal and in putty) is still asking for a password even though I have not set one in the keygen command.

Comment: I reformatted the sd card, reloaded Ubuntu core, then using my ubuntu workstation I deleted all of the certs I had used before and entries for trusted hosts.  I then regenerated the certs and uploaded the id_rsa.pub cert information to Ubuntu One.  I ran through the setup again on the RP3 and tried to ssh in from my Ubuntu workstation using the Name@IPADDRESS supplied from the RP3  and get an 'Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.'  error.

Comment: FOUND IT..  The answer came from here https://chrisjean.com/ubuntu-ssh-fix-for-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key/  Since I am trying to get there from the Gnome Desktop it is acting like this .. but it fixed it..

Comment: Would you consider posting an answer with details of the solution you found to help others in future? :)